# Listing the values of particular probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Three balls are selected at random from a bag containing
2 red , 3 green , and 4 blue balls.
Define the random variables
R = the number of red balls drawn,
and
G = the number of green balls drawn.
List the values of
(a) the joint probability mass function pR,G(r, g).
(b) the probability mass functions for R, pR(r), and for G, pG(g).
(c) the joint cumulative distribution function FR,G(r, g).
(d) the cumulative distribution functions for R, FR(r), and G, FG(g).

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, should I just be constructing tables showing probabilities for R=0 and G=0 etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Possible values for the random variables: $$R \in \{0,1,2\} \quad G \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$$

As you thought, we can construct tables: the first for the probability mass functions and the second for the cumulative distribution functions.

In the first table, each entry in the main square is $f_{R,G}(r,g)$:
$$
\begin{array}{cc|ccc|c}
&&& r && \\
& & 0 & 1 & 2 & f_G(g) \\
\hline
&0 & \dfrac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{4}{84} & \dfrac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{12}{84} & \dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{4}{84} & \dfrac{20}{84} \\
\\
& 1 & \dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{18}{84} & \dfrac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{24}{84} & \dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{3}{84} & \dfrac{45}{84} \\
g\\
& 2 & \dfrac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{12}{84} & \dfrac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{6}{84} & 0 & \dfrac{18}{84} \\
\\
& 3 & \dfrac{\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{9}{3}} = \dfrac{1}{84} & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{84} \\
\hline
& f_R(r) & \dfrac{35}{84} & \dfrac{42}{84} & \dfrac{7}{84} & \\
\end{array}
$$

$\\$

In the second table, each entry in the main square is $F_{R,G}(r,g)$:
$$
\begin{array}{cc|ccc|c}
&&& r && \\
& & 0 & 1 & 2 & F_G(g) \\
\hline
&0 & \quad \dfrac{4}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{16}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{20}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{20}{84} \\
\\
& 1 & \quad \dfrac{22}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{58}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{65}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{65}{84} \\
g\\
& 2 & \quad \dfrac{34}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{76}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{83}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{83}{84} \\
\\
& 3 & \quad \dfrac{35}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{77}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{84}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{84}{84} \\
\hline
& F_R(r) & \quad \dfrac{35}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{77}{84} \quad & \quad \dfrac{84}{84} \quad & 
\end{array}
$$